# TextRecognizer eating memory up to a crash

Tags: android

I use AI Vision in order to recognize text.
The problem is that I run it in a loop for about 100 images and the memory is getting lower and lower.
When I run: textRecognizer.process(image), than it crasher with message: Failed to allocate.
When I comment this line only, everything is OK.
How can I convince TextRecognizer to free up the memory?
Regards,

Comment: pls post the code, the loop one

Comment: Here is the code: https://github.com/jmall/problema/blob/main/demo.java Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials I came up to a simple solution.
In Manifest add the following line android:largeHeap="true"
This solved the problem!
Before this solution, the app crashed after 30 images. After the solution I ran over 500 images without a problem!